# How to decode DRM protected content (FairPlay, WideVine etc) using Video ToolBox on iOS?

Tags: ios, metal, drm, fairplay, video-toolbox

I have a custom player on iOS which can decode a HEVC stream using the HEVC decoder provided by the video toolbox, get the handle to the decoded frame, pass it to Metal and render the frame using Metal.  I would like to do the same with DRM encrypted content.  I understand that AVPlayer directly supports FairPlay and you can play DRM encrypted content using it ([sample](https://icapps.com/blog/how-integrate-basic-hls-stream-fairplay)).  How do I do it with Video ToolBox ?  I don't see any APIs to setup DRM session/keys in [VTDecompressionSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox/vtdecompressionsession).  Thanks.

Comment: since you posted this, did you find any solution? If so, could you please share it?